# A ball in a particular open set.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Let $\varepsilon >0$ and define the following open set $$U_\varepsilon=\left\{x\in U\;|\; \text{dist}(x,\partial U)>\varepsilon \right\}.$$

Now, let $x$ be a point of $U_{\varepsilon}$ and consider the closed ball $\overline{B}(x,\varepsilon)$.

> **Question 1.** Is it true or false that $$\overline{B}(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U_\varepsilon$$

> **Question 2.**
> Is it true or false that $$\overline{B}(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to draw a picture then you see what happens. Take for example $U=B(0,1)\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ and $\epsilon = 0.5$. How does $U_\epsilon$ look? (These are all points in $U$ having distance greater $0.5$ from the boundary of the circle). What happens if you put a ball of radius $0.5$ around an element in $U_\epsilon$?

Comment: The assertion $\overline{B}(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U_\epsilon$ then tells you all elements in this ball of radius $0.5$ should also have distance greater $0.5$ from the circle with radius $1$.

Comment: @GhostAmarth I am confused, now. Then, is false?

Comment: If $U=\mathbb{R}^n$ your question has a problem making sense. Do you assume $U\neq \mathbb{R}^n$ and nonempty?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes.

Comment: @NatMath Here's a picture: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/rjmcea8k

Comment: @GhostAmarth, then the answer is no. Thanks

Comment: It seems the question should be: "Is it true or false that $\overline{B}(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\overline B(x,{\varepsilon})$ might or might not be a subset of $U_{\varepsilon}.$

Example 1. Let $n=1$ and $U=(0,6)$ and let $\varepsilon=2$ and let $x=3.$ Then $\partial U=\{0,6\}$ and $\overline B(x,{\varepsilon})=[1,5]$ but $U_{\varepsilon}=(2,4).$

Example 2. Let $n=1$ and $U=(0,6)$ and let $\varepsilon=1$ and let $x=3.$ Then $\partial U=\{0,6\}$ and $\overline B(x,{\varepsilon})=[2,4] \subset (1,5)=U_{\varepsilon}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleetThanks! One last question: with these conditions, however, can we say that: $\overline{B}(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U?$

Comment: No. In my example, suppose $\varepsilon = 3.$

Answer (score 0):

First, note that by the definition of an open set, $\partial U$ is a set of points that are not in , but that can be approached arbitrarily closely by points in . In other words, for any point $y\in\partial U$, there exists a sequence of points $\{x_n\} \subset U$ such that the distance between $$ and $_$ goes to zero as  goes to infinity.

Let's consider a point $x \in U_\epsilon$. By definition, this means that the distance between $x$ and $\partial U$ is greater than $\epsilon$. In other words, for any point $y \in \partial U$, the distance between $$ and $$ is greater than $\epsilon$.

Consider the closed ball $(,)$. This is the set of all points that are a distance of at most  from . Since the distance between  and any point $y \in \partial U$ is greater than $\epsilon$, it follows that $(,)$ is a subset of $U$ (since no points in $(,)$ can be in $\partial U$).

What about $U_\epsilon$?